# Fabric.js background appears only after click

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

With the following code I create a Fabric canvas

```
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.setWidth(660);
canvas.setHeight(590);

fabric.Image.fromURL('assets/img/materials/marble.bmp', function(image) {
    image.set({
        // I need this because the image size and the canvas size could be different
        // in this way the image always covers the canvas
        width:660,
        height:590
    });

    canvas.setBackgroundImage(image);
});

canvas.renderAll();
```

The canvas is created, but the background image doesn't appear unless I click inside the canvas, as I click inside the canvas the background appears.

I'm working on my local machine and the application will not be published online.

Why do you think that I'm having this problem? Am I doing anything wrong? How could I fix this behaviour?

Comment: Try calling `canvas.renderAll()` in the callback `function(image)` - `fabric.Image.fromURL` is likely loading the image asynchronously, so the bottom line of of your code runs before the image is loaded.

Comment: Thank you, that works.
As comment I can't set your answer as the correct one.

Comment: You're welcome! That's allright - there's gazillions questions like this; it's probably going to be marked a duplicate by someone who can find the best answer to link to ;-)

Comment: FYI, this issue pertains to image objects too (not just background images). The below solution using `canvas.renderAll()` within callback seems to work.

Answer (score 5):

fabric.image.fromURL is asyncronous.
You have to call the renderAll() inside the callback if you want to show the backgroundimage asap.

Otherwise your mouse click will trigger a renderAll some fraction of second after the load is finished and the background will be rendered.

```
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.setWidth(660);
canvas.setHeight(590);

    fabric.Image.fromURL('assets/img/materials/marble.bmp', function(image) {
        image.set({
            // I need this because the image size and the canvas size could be different
            // in this way the image always covers the canvas
            width:660,
            height:590
        });

        canvas.setBackgroundImage(image);
        canvas.renderAll();
    });
```

Comment: Since `setBackgroundImage()` is also asynchronous, would it not be safer to invoke canvas.renderAll() inside the setBackgroundImage's optional callback parameter?  (I wish this library was Promise-friendly.)

Comment: Since `setBackgroundImage` receive an image object as argument should not be asyncronous. is it?

Comment: `setBackgroundImage` is asynchronous. It has an optional second argument for a callback. Perhaps that wasn't the case in earlier versions - I'm new to fabric. I just mentioned it in case I can save someone the trouble I had from not dealing with this nuance.

Comment: Theorically you do not need to use the callback in this case, you can also simply do `canvas.backgroundImage=image` and using renderAll or requestRenderall

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Safari iOS would not render the background ~20-60% of the time (version `"fabric": "^4.3.1"`). Waiting did not resolve. Tapping the canvas would activate/render the background. Adding `renderAll()` in various places did not resolve it for me. Did not happen on Chrome, only Safari iOS (ver. 14.1 at the time)

### B64 workaround:

Dropping the `fabric.Image.fromURL` and instead providing a b64 image to `setBackgroundImage` worked for me consistently with all browsers.

```js
let myImg = `data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64,<- base64 data->`

this.canvasObj.setBackgroundImage(
  myImg, //b64
  this.canvasObj.renderAll.bind(this.canvasObj)
);
```